# Undefined method 'call' for :conditions Rails 4.1 after upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have recently upgraded to Rails 4.1 from 4.0.4.
I have code a little like this:

```
Model.foo.each do |model|
  model.update_attributes (foo: bar)
end
```

and `Model.foo.count` but I get an error

```
undefined method `call' for {:conditions=>{:foo=>bar}}:Hash
```

What could be going wrong?

Answer from below - problem with old style code in scope in model.rb

My scope used to look like this:

`scope :pro, :conditions => {:pro => true}`

and now it looks like this:

`scope :pro, -> { where(pro: true) }`

Comment: what does `Model.foo` look like in the console, it returns a hash I take it?

Comment: what if you remove the white space after `update_attributes` ?

Comment: it seems that you have some strage code in the model `Model` how it look like?

Comment: I am going to remove the question, updated for now to give you guys trying to help me some feedback as to what I was doing wrong before I delete it

Comment: Just decided to edit it instead so other people may find it useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 'foo' is a scope, you might've forgotten to lambda-ize the condition.

Try this in the model:

```
scope :foo, -> { where(condition) }
```